# Why the module `ClassMethods` defined and extended in the same namespace?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to understand code from github [repo](https://github.com/peter-murach/github/blob/master/lib/github_api.rb#L15). It's the main module of the gem to setup the client.

```
module Github
  # more code
  class << self
    def included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods # what would this be for?
    end
    def new(options = {}, &block)
      Client.new(options, &block)
    end
    def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
      if new.respond_to?(method_name)
        new.send(method_name, *args, &block)
      elsif configuration.respond_to?(method_name)
        Github.configuration.send(method_name, *args, &block)
      else
        super
      end
    end
    def respond_to?(method_name, include_private = false)
      new.respond_to?(method_name, include_private) ||
      configuration.respond_to?(method_name) ||
      super(method_name, include_private)
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def require_all(prefix, *libs)
      libs.each do |lib|
        require "#{File.join(prefix, lib)}"
      end
    end
    # more methods ...
  end

  extend ClassMethods
  require_all LIBDIR,
    'authorization',
    'validations',
    'normalizer',
    'parameter_filter',
    'api',
    'client',
    'pagination',
    'request',
    'response',
    'response_wrapper',
    'error',
    'mime_type',
    'page_links',
    'paged_request',
    'page_iterator',
    'params_hash'

end
```

1. Why is `class << self` and `module ClassMethods` used, and then extended instead of being included in the `class << self` part?
2. There is a class method `def included(base)`. This seems to add the class methods into a specific object. Why is it like this? It could relate to the functionality of the class, but I do not understand it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
module MyModule
  class << self
    def included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods # what would this be for?
    end
    <...>
  end
  <...>
end
```

This is actually a pretty common practice in Ruby. Basically, what it's saying is: when some object performs `include MyModule`, make it also `extend MyModule::ClassMethods`. Such a feat is useful if you want a mixin that adds some methods not just to the instances of a class, but to the class itself.

A short example:

```
module M
  # A normal instance method
  def mul
    @x * @y
  end
 
  module ClassMethods
    # A class method
    def factory(x)
      new(x, 2 * x)
    end
  end
 
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
end
 
class P
  include M
  def initialize(x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end
 
  def sum
    @x + @y
  end
end
 
p1 = P.new(5, 15)
puts "#{p1.sum} #{p1.mul}" # <= 20 75

# Calling the class method from the module here!
p2 = P.factory(10)
puts "#{p2.sum} #{p2.mul}" # <= 30 200
```

Comment: That makes sense. I am a little confused about the method `self.included(base)`, could you maybe explain what that is for and how it relates to module `M` or class `P`

Comment: when `P`  calls `include M`, ruby automatically calls  `included` on `M` if it is defined.   It is a callback of the include method.   This is use to extend the module's class methods onto `P`.   See: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-included

Comment: Is there any chance you could point me to a practical example of this? I am still not clear on the situations it would be used in. I am sure i just need to see a practical example to understand it's true application.

Answer (score 4):

Looking more at the [repo](https://github.com/peter-murach/github/blob/master/lib/github_api/api.rb) there is another class `Github::API`. This class seems to require functionality of the `Github::ClassMethods` module.

```
module Github
  # Core class responsible for api interface operations
  class API
    extend Github::ClassMethods
```

So it makes sense that it's own own module. It gives the ability to only import those methods. If the methods from `class << self` were included, they would become available which is probably not wanted.

It may have been better to have the module in it's own class or named something else. But I guess that is just personal choice.